# PHP OOP - Wrong variables returned?

Tags: php, oop, variables

Ok, so, with the code below:

```
class Core {
    public $child;
    public function start() {
        $child = Loader::instance('Child');
        print_r($this);
    }
}

class Loader extends Core {
    public static $instances;

    public static function instance($class) {
        if(!isset(self::$instances[$class])) {
            self::$instances[$class] = new $class();
        }

        return self::$instances[$class];
    }
}

class Child extends Core {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->child = 'test';
    }
}

Loader::instance('Core')->start();
```

I should be able after a print_r($this) to see:

```
Core Object
(
    [child] => test
)
```

instead of

```
Core Object
(
    [child] => 
)
```

what is happening now?

Thanks again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `start()` method of `Core` class you use variable `$child`, that is not the property of the object. Instead write:

```
class Core {
    public $child;
    public function start() {
        $this->child = Loader::instance('Child')->child;
        print_r($this);
    }
}
```

and tell me, whether this is what you wanted to accomplish.

**EDIT:**

I believe you can achieve what you want by referencing static variables. But be careful, how they work. Moreover, you will not see the result by invoking `print_r()`.

Here is the code:

```
class Core {
    static $child;
    public function start() {

        // invoking code that changes Core::$child inside
        $child = Loader::instance('Child');

        print_r($this);
    }
}
```

and

```
class Child extends Core {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // changing static variable $child of both Core and Child
        self::$child = 'test';
    }
}
```

Comment: `code`class Child extends Core {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->variable = 'test';
    }
}

Comment: @Gabriel I have updated answer (added `->child`). Does it work for you now?

Comment: Yes.. now my question is: if I do the follow `class Child extends Core {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->child = 'test';
    }
}` I can't auto-update Core->child variable with 'test' value?

Comment: In that case object of class `Child` _is_ the instance of `Core` class. In these terms you are already doing it. But if you are talking about $child being instance of class `Child` and $core being instance of class `Core`, then you have to separately change the value of `$core->child`. It is not done automatically, as object of class `Core` is not the same as object of class `Child`. They are only similar in types. This is basic understanding of how classes work.

Comment: I have updated the answer - you may be looking for static variables, but you should know how they work. And they won't be displayed when the print_r is invoked.

Comment: No problem. I am just curious: is it what you were looking for?

Comment: I wanted to manipulate Core, from any class, I made my implementation, using your example as a basis, and is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$child = Loader::instance('Child');
```

Shoulld be:

```
$this->child = Loader::instance('Child');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where your print_r output comes from:

```
    $child = Loader::instance('Child');
    print_r($this);
```

And it will print the current object (`$this` is a `Core`), rather than the newly instantiated $child (which would be a `Child` class).